# How do I split a file into list using white spaces and new line in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, file, split, bellman-ford

I have a config.txt file having data in the following format

```
2
B 6.5 5001
F 2.2 5005
```

The first line of this file indicates the number of neighbors for Router A. Following this, there is one line dedicated to each
neighbor. It starts with the neighbor ID, followed by the cost to reach this neighbor and finally the port number that this neighbor is using for listening.

I am trying to implement bellman-Ford routing algorithm and for that I am passing this file as command line argument.

I want to make it into a list in order to store it into a data structure for later use but I am not sure whether the list would contain only 3 elements i.e the 3 lines?

Or I need to split each string by whitespace/store each string in every line separated by whitespace, into a list.

I am able to use split function to make a list of the 3 lines but how do I make a list of the strings/characters within a line?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always do a double-split - first by line, then by whitespace:

```
data = """2
B 6.5 5001
F 2.2 5005"""

parsed = [line.split() for line in data.split("\n") if line]
# [['2'], ['B', '6.5', '5001'], ['F', '2.2', '5005']]
```

You can then iterate through it and convert your fields to whatever you need.